# scrollable ul element without scrollbar

Tags: css, angularjs, html-lists

I'm trying to use angular to create list of elements. The page will be an app on mobile phone.
 The list itself can have many elements so what I expect is that the ul element should be scrollable ("swipable"?). I tried to follow some example like http://jsfiddle.net/sirrocco/9z48t/ and http://jsfiddle.net/qcv5Q/1/..

This is the html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="spinner-icon" style="display:none">
        <span class = "icon-spinner"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 indentation push-down bg-white" ng-repeat="cei in completeElementInfo">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h4>{{cei.description}}</h4>
                <p>{{cei.name}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="log-widget-list">
            <ul class="list scroller clearfix" id="elements-list">
                <li class="pull-left" ng-repeat="tinfo in cei.techInfo | orderBy: 'tinfo.sentTime'">
                    <h4 class="align-center">{{tinfo.elementShortCode}}</h4>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <span class="icon-clock pull-left"></span>
                        <span class="pull-right"> {{tinfo.sentTime}}min</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css code:

```
.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.log-widget-list {
    height:100px;
    width: 720px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.log-widget-list .scroller{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 1500px; /* combined width of all LI's */
}

#elements-list li {
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: none!important;
  background-color: #0accf8;
  padding: 4px;
}

#elements-list li:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: 3px solid #ffffff;
}

#elements-list [class^="icon-"], #elements-list [class*=" icon-"] {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Now the problem is that i don't want that the horizontal scrollbar appears, but it appears and i don't understand why... Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

add `overflow:hidden` in `#wrapper` css.

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
 background: transparent;
 width: 550px;
 color: white;
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/9z48t/5/

Comment: I put it... The scrollbar is still visible. I am trying to get a horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/FTUrF/6/

Changed some CSS here:

```
 .log-widget-list {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.log-widget-list .scroller {
    width: 215px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Added `height` and `padding-bottom` in `.scroller` and `border` in `.log-widget-list`

and added some more of these:

```
<span class="pull-right"> {{tinfo.sentTime}}min</span>
```